# why do I get Path expected for join when I use join key word in hql

Tags: hibernate, join

I have the following HQL

```
String FIND_PRODUCT_CLASS_ID = "SELECT pc.id FROM ProductClass pc"+ 
" JOIN ProductGroup pg ON pc.id = pg.productClassId" +
" JOIN Product p ON pg.id = p.id" +
" JOIN ProductSub ps ON p.id = ps.productId WHERE ps.id =:childProductSubId";
```

When I run this query in Spring Hibernate environment, I get the following stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT pc.id FROM com.xxx.domain.ProductClass pc JOIN ProductGroup pg ON pc.id = pg.productClassId JOIN Product p ON pg.id = p.id JOIN ProductSub ps ON p.id = ps.productId WHERE ps.id =:childProductSubId]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
... 146 more
```

However, if I modifiy the query without `join` keyword like below, it's succeeded.

```
String FIND_PRODUCT_CLASS_ID = "SELECT pc.id FROM ProductClass pc, ProductGroup pg, " +
 " Product p, ProductSub ps where pc.id = pg.productClassId "+
 " and pg.id = p.id and p.id = ps.productId and ps.id =:childProductSubId";
```

I know that I have already found the solution but I'm not sure why it doesn't work with `join` key word in HQL.  Can sombody explain this to me please? Is this something to do with the mapping? In my case objects are mapped in Hibernate layer.

Comment: This is because of the `ON` in your query and an old version of Hibernate. See http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/03/join-unrelated-entities-in-jpa.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We need to provide path in HQL query.
That's the "Path expected for join" the exception is coming.

change query something like below: Please edit as per use

```
String FIND_PRODUCT_CLASS_ID = "SELECT pc.id FROM ProductClass pc"+ 
" JOIN pc.ProductGroup pg " +
" JOIN pg.Product p " +
" JOIN p.ProductSub ps WHERE ps.id =:childProductSubId";'
```

Please refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: i have no idea what this means at all

Comment: please explain your answer in more detail

Answer (score 2):

Since Hibernate 5.1 you can join unrelated entities using SQL like syntax joins.

**In case you still get the** `antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!` **error
you might have to use the full class name including the package e.g.**

```
String FIND_PRODUCT_CLASS_ID = "SELECT pc.id FROM ProductClass pc"+ 
" JOIN com.mypackage.ProductGroup pg ON pc.id = pg.productClassId" +
" JOIN com.mypackage.Product p ON pg.id = p.id" +
" JOIN com.mypackage.ProductSub ps ON p.id = ps.productId WHERE ps.id =:childProductSubId";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to probably do something like this. Then you can join using user.Address ad and refer to Address declared variables using ad.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

}
```