# Spring Data, JPA and LEFT JOIN on unrelated tables

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have this 1-N case

```
class BaseEntity {

  @Id
  Long id;

  String name;
}

class RelId {

  @Column(name = "BU_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
  private Long buId;

  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
  private Long id;
}

class ExtA {

  @EmbeddedId
  private RelId id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private BaseEntity baseEntity;
}

class ExtB {

  @EmbeddedId
  private RelId id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private BaseEntity baseEntity;
}

class BaseEntityEx {

  BaseEntity baseEntity;
  ExtA extA;
  ExtB extB;
}
```

Now I would like to select the BaseEntityEx where the `buId` is equals to `2` with a query like this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW BaseEntityEx(b, ea, eb)
      + " FROM BaseEntity b "
      + " LEFT JOIN ExtA ea ON (ea.id.id=b.id AND ea.id.buId=:buId)"
      + " LEFT JOIN ExtB eb ON (eb.id.id=b.id AND eb.id.buId=:buId)"
      + " WHERE"
      + "   b.id=:id")
public BaseEntityEx getBaseEntityExByRelId(@Param("buId") long buId, @Param("id") long id);
```

But it does not work.
How can I do that?

> P.S. I would like to keep the relation only on ExtA and ExtB because when I
>   use BaseEntity I don't want to load lazily or not hundreds of
>   relations.

The error that I obtain is:

```
antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!
```

Comment: Define please "not working". Is there any error? or just no data? Have you seend sql in logs?

Comment: `antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!`

Comment: maybe refer to this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672196/why-do-i-get-path-expected-for-join-when-i-use-join-key-word-in-hql/43672309

Comment: I would like to keep the relation only on ExtA and ExtB because when I use BaseEntity I don't want to load lazily or not hundreds of relations.

Comment: So then use JOIN FETCH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate

Comment: but I don't have the relation from BaseEntity to the other entities